# MySQL sorting by custom pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I'm trying to select information from a MySQL database table, following a custom pattern to sort the results.

**What I want to achieve**

I have a column in my table that can have 4 different values (types of entry).

Let's call them AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD and the pattern should be something like:

```
AAA
AAA
BBB
AAA
CCC
DDD
```

So I would like a table to sort like this:

```
Before    After
 AAA       AAA
 AAA       AAA
 AAA       BBB
 AAA       AAA
 AAA       CCC
 BBB       DDD
 BBB       AAA
 CCC       AAA
 DDD       BBB
```

I have tried the [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function, but it doesn't sort them in pattern.

I was thinking of using another table for sorting, but I will have different queries with different results and I want the pattern to always start the same way.

Since I'm not sure that this option even exists in MySQL I'm open to any suggestions and workarounds.

**EDIT**

OK, I did a big mistake by not saying this. The table has multiple columns, and ID as a AI primary key. The column with AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD is the one from which depends the sorting.

So I want to order my query by this column, but in the way described abouve.

Comment: I don't understand the pattern

Comment: Okay, I guess the problem is with me then. Let me try to edit the question and make it better.

Comment: Is there any other column which tells the difference between the third and the first two AAAAs in your pattern?

Comment: No other than they are different entries with different ID's. I was thinking of an array of values for the query to loop trough, but I don't find anything similar, so I guess I'm just thinking too much...

Comment: I did a edit on my question. I hope it is a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it's fair to say that, **usually**, if a single column in a **relational** database table can have the **same** value in more than one record, there would **tend** to be values in other columns that give the record a distinct meaning, or a distinct place in the ordering of records.

You're focusing on one column, when you'd likely need to include at least one other item of information to provide the ordering.  If that other information isn't in the database, then it probably needs to be put in the database.

Comment: I agree with you. This is not my only column. Please check my edit in the question above.